# d3 Tree - drag and relocate nodes in d3 graphs is possible?

Tags: d3.js, graph, tree

Is it possible to use D3 Trees and draw graph. Then let the user to rearange the nodes without changing their relationships?

Comment: Yes, this would be possible. Do you have a specific question in implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used d3 Tree functions to have the location of nodes and used my current forced directed graph. This way I could keep my current functionalities, and also having more than one parent for nodes, and user could move the nodes around. However, once user moves the node, I do not let d3 to rearrange the node when nodes is expanded. I want the node stays in the location that user moved and wants.

Comment: Do you mind, to share a snippet? As I am searching a similar functionality.